# Angular 4 not send cookie to server

Tags: javascript, angular, laravel

When I use `withCredentials` I can see that cookies are sent to the server, but are send anything to the server. I use laravel as backend and angular 4 as frontend.
Also, the cookie not shown on chrome developer tools and I can't access them using.

Also, I used Cors middleware in laravel like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      $response = $next($request);
      $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
      $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
      $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
      $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Disposition, x-total-count, x-filename');
      $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

      return $response;

    }
}
```

and when I request first time to the server for set cookie, these below response show:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Content-Disposition, x-total-count, x-filename
Cache-Control:no-cache, private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 02 Jan 2018 09:04:32 GMT
Server:nginx/1.11.9
Set-Cookie:refreshToken=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; expires=Sun, 25-Aug-2019 09:04:32 GMT; Max-Age=51840000; path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-RateLimit-Limit:60
X-RateLimit-Remaining:58
```

and when I request from frontend:

```
refreshToken(){

const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.getToken()})
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
return this.http.post(API_DOMAIN + 'refresh', JSON.stringify({}), options)
  .map(
    (response) => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json()
    },
  )
  .do(
    tokenData =>{
      localStorage.setItem('token', tokenData.access_token)
      localStorage.setItem('expires_in', tokenData.expires_in)
    }
  )
}
```

Chrome developer:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Content-Disposition, x-total-count, x-filename
Cache-Control:no-cache, private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 02 Jan 2018 08:57:28 GMT
Server:nginx/1.11.9
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-RateLimit-Limit:60
X-RateLimit-Remaining:59
```

Front and back servers use different ports.

Comment: Does your Laravel server run of `localhost` too? Why do you need CORS?

Comment: @Dmitry no. my laravel server run on homestead and domian like: mydomian.test

Comment: You can't send/receive cookies to/from another domain. You need to either proxy to your Laravel server (can be configured in angular) or use another authentication method like JWT or other token based authentication.

Comment: @Dmitry I used laravel passport for authentication and write middleware in laravel server!

Comment: Ah, so they are not authentication cookies. But you can't send any cookies to another domain anyway. You can use proxy and then you can disable CORS since it will work on the same domain. You only need proxy for development since when you publish your entire app will be in Laravel's `public` directory. Do you want me to post how to configure the proxy?

Comment: @Dmitry how can I configure a proxy? can you help me? i used this link to build token based authentication with laravel passport:
http://esbenp.github.io/2017/03/19/modern-rest-api-laravel-part-4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162348/discussion-between-zione01-and-dmitry).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't save cookies because your development node.js server and your Laravel Vagrant box are on different domains. What you can do is to proxy calls from node.js to the the Laravel server.

Create `proxy.conf.json` in the root of Angular app. Put an object with routes inside:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://mydomian.test/",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

I just have `/api` defined here because all my backend URIs are inside `api.php`. All calls that look like `http://localhost:4200/api/someitems/1` will be proxied to `http://mydomian.test/api/someitems/1`. 
Then edit `package.json` and change the value of `start` inside `scripts` to `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`. Now `npm run start` will start with proxy. The problem I had with this proxy is that it resolves your URL (`http://mydomian.test/`) to an IP. When it calls Laravel with just an IP the *nginx* server does not know what to do because it must receive a domain name. *nginx* allows multiple website on the same IP so it must receive a domain name or to have a default website to which it redirects all calls those have no domain name. In case this is still not fixed in Angular's proxy go to `/etc/nginx/sites-available` on the Laravel machine, you'll have a `mydomian.test` config file there. It has `listen 80;` line there, change it to `listen 80 default;`.

Now you can change the `API_DOMAIN` variable to `http://localhost:4200` (or remove it all together) and disable the CORS.